# React apply function to single item in array

Tags: arrays, reactjs

The following code creates a simple movie rating app. Everything works except that when an up or down vote is clicked in one of the array items, the votes state for all items in the array update, rather than just for the item that was clicked. How do I code this so that the vote only applies to the item where it was clicked?

```
class Ratings extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            votes: 0
        };
        this.add = this.add.bind(this);
        this.subtract = this.subtract.bind(this);
        this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
    }
    add(event){
        this.setState ({
            votes: this.state.votes + 1
        })
    }
    subtract(event){
        this.setState ({
            votes: this.state.votes - 1
        })
    }
    reset(event){
        this.setState ({
            votes: 0
        })
    }
    render () {
        this.movies = this.props.list.map(x => {
            return (
                <div key={x.id} className="movierater">
                <MoviePoster poster={x.img}/>
                <h1 className="title">{x.name}</h1>
                    <div className="votewrapper">
                        <button onClick={this.add}><i className="votebutton fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        <Votes count={this.state.votes} />
                        <button onClick={this.subtract}><i className="votebutton fa fa-thumbs-o-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </div>
                <button onClick={this.reset} className="reset">Reset</button>
                </div>
            )
        });
        return (
            <div>
                {this.movies}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function MoviePoster(props) {
    return (
        <img src={props.poster} alt="Movie Poster" className="poster"/>
    );
}

function Votes(props) {
    return (
        <h2>Votes: {props.count}</h2>
    );
}

var movieposters = [
    {id: 1, img:"http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_alien_covenant_ver4.jpg", name: "Alien Covenant"},
    {id: 2, img:"http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_atomic_blonde_ver4.jpg", name: "Atomic Blonde"},
    {id: 3, img:"http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_easy_living_ver3.jpg", name: "Easy Living"},
    {id: 4, img:"http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_once_upon_a_time_in_venice_ver3.jpg", name: "Once Upon a Time in Venice"},
    {id: 5, img:"http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_scorched_earth.jpg", name: "Scorched Earth"},
    {id: 6, img:"http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_underworld_blood_wars_ver9.jpg", name: "Underworld: Blood Wars"},
    {id: 7, img:"http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_void.jpg", name: "The Void"},
    {id: 8, img:"http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_war_for_the_planet_of_the_apes.jpg", name: "War for the Planet of the Apes"},
]


ReactDOM.render(
    <Ratings list={movieposters} />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a separate vote count for each movie entity.
This can be accomplished by providing an id to each movie and setting the vote for that specific movie by id.

I would also recommend to extract a new component for a `Movie`.
this component will get the `movieId` as a prop and the handlers, it will invoke the up or down handlers and provide to them the current `movieId`.

See a running example:

```js
class Movie extends React.Component {
  onSubtract = () => {
    const { subtract, movieId } = this.props;
    subtract(movieId);
  };

  onAdd = () => {
    const { add, movieId } = this.props;
    add(movieId);
  };

  onReset = () => {
    const { reset, movieId } = this.props;
    reset(movieId);
  };

  render() {
    const { movie, votes = 0 } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="movierater">
        <MoviePoster poster={movie.img} />
        <h1 className="title">{movie.name}</h1>
        <div className="votewrapper">
          <button onClick={this.onAdd}>
            <i className="votebutton fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true" />
          </button>
          <Votes count={votes} />
          <button onClick={this.onSubtract}>
            <i className="votebutton fa fa-thumbs-o-down" aria-hidden="true" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.onReset} className="reset">
          Reset
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Ratings extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      allVotes: {}
    };
  }

  subtract = movieId => {
    const { allVotes } = this.state;
    const currentVote = allVotes[movieId] || 0;
    const nextState = {
      ...allVotes,
      [movieId]: currentVote - 1
    };
    this.setState({allVotes: nextState});
  };

  add = movieId => {
    const { allVotes } = this.state;
    const currentVote = allVotes[movieId] || 0;
    const nextState = {
      ...allVotes,
      [movieId]: currentVote + 1
    };
    this.setState({ allVotes: nextState });
  };

  reset = movieId => {
    const { allVotes } = this.state;
    const nextState = {
      ...allVotes,
      [movieId]: 0
    };
    this.setState({ allVotes: nextState });
  };

  render() {
    const { allVotes } = this.state;
    this.movies = this.props.list.map(x => {
      const votes = allVotes[x.id];
      return (
        <Movie
          movieId={x.id}
          movie={x}
          votes={votes}
          reset={this.reset}
          subtract={this.subtract}
          add={this.add}
        />
      );
    });
    return <div>{this.movies}</div>;
  }
}

function MoviePoster(props) {
  return <img src={props.poster} alt="Movie Poster" className="poster" />;
}

function Votes(props) {
  return <h2>Votes: {props.count}</h2>;
}

var movieposters = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: "http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_alien_covenant_ver4.jpg",
    name: "Alien Covenant"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    img: "http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_atomic_blonde_ver4.jpg",
    name: "Atomic Blonde"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    img: "http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_easy_living_ver3.jpg",
    name: "Easy Living"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    img:
      "http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_once_upon_a_time_in_venice_ver3.jpg",
    name: "Once Upon a Time in Venice"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    img: "http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_scorched_earth.jpg",
    name: "Scorched Earth"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    img:
      "http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_underworld_blood_wars_ver9.jpg",
    name: "Underworld: Blood Wars"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    img: "http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_void.jpg",
    name: "The Void"
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    img:
      "http://www.impawards.com/2017/posters/med_war_for_the_planet_of_the_apes.jpg",
    name: "War for the Planet of the Apes"
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(<Ratings list={movieposters} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thx, Sag1v. I kinda thought the solution was more complicated than I realized. I implemented your code and it worked. I'll have to put some time in to understanding it. Really appreciate how much effort you put in to answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of votes for each element, thus this.state.votes +/- 1 doesn't do the job, so:

Change

```
this.state = {
   votes: 0
}
```

to

```
this.state = {
   votes: {}
}
```

then change the functions:

```
add(id){
   return function(event) {
      this.setState ({ ...this.state.votes, [id]: parseInt(this.state.votes[id]) + 1 })
   }
}
```

and the same for subtract. Then change your buttons to:

```
<button onClick={this.add(x.id)} ... (same for subtract)
```

and last change your Vote component:

```
<Votes count={this.state.votes[x.id] || 0} />
```

On reset just do:

```
reset(event){
   this.setState ({ votes: {} })
}
```

Comment: Hey Arber. Thx. I made the changes you suggested but while the array outputs to the DOM nothing happens when I click the buttons. Wouldn't I need to make a change to the Votes function as well?